# Having some trouble with JQuery Mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

This is some code I working on but now of JQuery Mobiles elements are working. It been a while since I have coded. Also if it important I am using Sumlime Text 2.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>.......</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div date-role="page" data-theme="a">
        <div date-role="header">
            <!--Main Nav Bar-->
            <a href="MainPage.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="right">Home</a>
            <h1>HOME</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            hello
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it, everything seems to be written correctly. The only thing that could be is that it does not use the correct HTML 5 doc type but html4. Jquery mobile is heavily reliant on HTML5

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>HTML5 Template</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i wrote it in sublime text is that the problem

Comment: Ahh, good to hear. You should switch the the html5 doctype though, just some food for thought.